# Why should I use Docker when I control my dev, staging and prod environment?

Tags: docker, use-case

I know the whole fact that it's better to have exactly what the production environment is on a development workstation: it erases the "it works on my computer".

Docker for me it's like [Bruce Lee on steroids fighting Abdul Jabbar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ic2k2P_FG0): if you need to use a VM, use Docker instead.

If, on development, I use nuget to control my dependencies, on my build server, it restores the packages before deployment: then I have exactly what the app needs to run.

Furthermore, it the same app I am deploying over and over again on the same boxes. Why would I need a restart policy when I must know what went wrong ? If the app dies, the other boxes will take the load and I need to investigate/fix and not get into the habits of "no big deal, the container will restart in a minute".

In a cloud environment, I see the point : AWS, Azure are those who can benefit the most of those features. Like being able to move webapps from server to server fast when customers ask for more power. Furthermore, if those webapps are different then I need to isolate them from each other: great use case of Docker!

But, on premise / colocation, if I have a powershell script to get me a bare metal server on foot with IIS ready: why would I introduce another layer of abstraction?

Comment: Two words: state drift

Comment: @BMitch How can state drift can happen when everything is under source control ? All the scripts and source code (packages.config) are under source control

Comment: If you don't need an OS or any dependencies to run your app, then that might be the case.

Comment: A working app is usually a combination of: (1) source/compiled code, (2) source/compiled dependencies, (3) bare operating system, (4) environment settings and (5) environment software. If you can create (3) with your Powershell script, and push your code (1) and pull your deps (2) with a dependency manager, then you're still missing (4) and (5). That can be combatted to some degree with orchestration software, but Docker wraps it up in a nice immutable image.

Comment: @l5o161b9kyit sorry for the short comments, I was rushing out the door without the time to give a proper answer. There was no sarcasm intended. I didn't give you a down vote, but did vtc as an overly broad question. The devops.se or serverfault.se may be a better fit for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First two answers I thought of (there are more, but I think these are the most important):

1. Resource utilization - if you're bare metal, your unit of scale is likely an entire VM. As you run more than one instance of an application or service, you can only do so by running more VMs. The canonical example of this in my world is IIS websites, where I can only get one instance per machine. If I run three instances, I have three VMs that are grossly underutilized. Docker allows you to replicate apps within a single VM. You can use up more resources on a single VM before scaling them horizontally.
2. App-specific dependencies - you manage the VM image and OS dependencies, but there might be cases where you want to tune that more specifically for your app. Versions of IIS, for example. Instead of needing to run one version of a dependency for all of your applications globally, you can build container images that are app-specific, which makes your runtime more predictable.
3. Deployment independence - if you're depending on global dependencies, you're locking yourself into updating all apps at once instead of being able to independently deploy each. Your deployments are larger and riskier. Containers would allow you to update each at your own pace and deliver value more incrementally.

Comment: 1 - I don't really use VMs. We throw every Apps directly on bare metal on the IIS installed on it. We segregate using AppPools. 

2- When we upgrade, we update the whole stack of everyone. For example, if we upgrade the .net framework, every app get the upgrade. It's like the c# version. We now use interesting features from 7.3 everywhere. But when 8 will be released, every project will be on it too (no workaround if 8 has a better way to solve a problem). If for example we use newtonsoft and a project use the last version, every other projects are upgraded too.

Comment: If you don't use VMs then I think point 1 becomes even more important. In order to scale your application, you need to buy more physical hardware instead of using virtualization to run more instances within a single unit of hardware.

Also to your second point, you've locked yourself into updating all apps at once instead of being able to independently deploy each. Your deployments are larger and riskier. Containers would allow you to update each at your own pace and deliver value more incrementally.

Comment: We scale up first. We only own 4 front end (2 master and 2 failover). We have one database and a replica of it which is always ready to take charge. That configuration is taking well the load with have. We are an SAAS  company so we don't really run multiple instances of the same app. Right now, the app servers contain the web app and the api. If we reach the horizontal scaling point, we have powershell scripts that can setup a whole box and CD server will take care of the rest. We are not the size of AWS. 5 years from now, we'll probably have 10 web servers to deploy on.

Comment: If you have 4 web servers today and might expand to 10, how much do the 6 new servers cost (purchase, licensing and maintenance)? Could you horizontally scale your existing workload within your existing 4 servers instead of pay for additional hardware? How do you ensure the web and API apps are all the same version across all 4-10 servers? How do you roll back failed deployments?

Comment: Horizontal scaling is on last resort. We scale up first. So yeah, we scale up first before thinking of buying new boxes. We continuously deploy so every server is always up to date. The build server is taking care of dependencies : restoring nuget packages. When we deploy, the CD server actually make a ready copy of the current website / api. That copy does not take a load at all and use close to no ressources. Then the CD server deploy the current version. If something goes wrong, we switch all requests to the ready copy.

Comment: I think the pragmatic answer is that you need to do the pros/cons math. There are benefits to running applications in containers (as noted above), but there are also costs to retooling your app, infra and deployment process. If those benefits don't outweigh the costs over a defined time horizon, then the answer is "containers aren't for you." I personally like the power of versioning deployments and environment consistency but not every situation here is alike. Let me know if you have more specific questions